# Over the air distribution stopped working XCode7.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ota

I updated XCode to 7.1.1.
Now archives I produce do not install over-the-air as they used to.

1st of all, the installation tries to ADD another copy of the app not to UPDATE as usual, though all bundle ids are the same, it is the same app and install was working like yesterday.

2nd, progress goes almost all the way and then it just disappears, no errors, NOTHING!

I re-checked, re-install all certificates etc - no help.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there will be no issues. When you try over the air installation, first it shows another copy of your app as being installed. After completing the installation (finishing the installation progress) it removes the new copy and the changes will be available with the original app.

You can check it by verifying the new features or anything you added to the new build, which will be available with the currently installed app.

Comment: wow, you are absolutely right. it updated old app as you said. weird though that it did not show the progress on top of it. Thanks a lot for clarifications.